# ¿Usar modo de validación distinto en un campo específico con react-hook-form?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

Estoy usando un form con react-hook-form, cuya inicialización es la siguiente:

`const formMethods = useForm({ mode: 'onChange' })`

Ahora bien, en uno de los inputs necesito que el `mode` sea `onBlur`, sin embargo no llego a encontrar la manera de que esto se pueda hacer. ¿Conocen alguna manera de lograrlo?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentación, `mode` indica la estrategia de validación del formulario, es decir, cuándo se van a ejecutar las validaciones para los inputs registrados.

Si lo que querés hacer es que un input no se valide cada vez que cambia (o sea, `onChange`) sino más bien cada vez que pierde foco (o sea, `onBlur`) lo que debés hacer es usar la función [`trigger`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/trigger), que lanza la validación manualmente.

O sea, **deberías quitar el modo de validación** de `useForm()` y luego en cada input hacer lo siguiente:

```
//en caso de que el input solo se deba validar onChange
<input 
  {...register("nombreInput1")} 
  onChange={
    (e) => {
      setValue("nombreInput1", e.target.value); 
      trigger("nombreInput1");
    } 
  }
/>
    
//en caso que el input solo se deba validar onBlur
<input 
  {...register("nombreInput2")} 
  onBlur={
    () => trigger("nombreInput2")
  } 
/>
```

Es la solución que se me ocurre, ya que el modo de validación que le pasamos al `useForm()` aplica a todos los inputs registrados en el formulario.

-Ado

Edit: `setValue` es una función que devuelve el useForm(), así como `register`.